# How To Transform A Hashmap To Embed Column Values Into Each nth-Row

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a hashmap `h1` such that:

```
h1 = {
  'Title': [t1, ... tn],
  'Price': [p1, ... pn],
  'Rating': [r1, ... rn]
}
```

I want to transpose this data into an array `arr1` such that:

```
arr1 = [
  {'Title': t1, 'Rating': r1, 'Price': p1},
  {'Title': t2, 'Rating': r2, 'Price': p2},
  [...]
  {'Title': tn, 'Rating': rn, 'Price': pn},
]
```

I ran the following code to manually perform this operation but I want to know if there is a more **performant** algorithm in the Python standard library that would achieve the same thing faster and with more **syntactic clarity** from the perspective of a human. Thanks.

```py
# I feel the code below is not very 'Pythonic' and would like to learn from others what a better method would be.

arr1 = []

for i in range(1, len(books_dict['Title'])):
  book = {
    'Title': books_dict['Title'][i],
    'Price': books_dict['Price'][i],
    'Rating': books_dict['Rating'][i]
  }
  # => {'Title': 'Tipping the Velvet', 'Price': 53.74, 'Rating': 1}
  arr1.append(book)
```

p.s. I am new to Python, so any tips & suggestions on the way I comment or structure code would be welcome too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip()` with list comprehension

```
h1 = {
      'Title': ['t1', 't2', 'tn'],
      'Price': ['p1', 'p2', 'pn'],
      'Rating': ['r1', 'r2', 'rn']
     }

res = [dict(zip(h1.keys(), v)) for v in zip(*h1.values())]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Title': 't1', 'Price': 'p1', 'Rating': 'r1'},
 {'Title': 't2', 'Price': 'p2', 'Rating': 'r2'},
 {'Title': 'tn', 'Price': 'pn', 'Rating': 'rn'}]
```

Comment: For sticking to the pure standard python library, this is about as elegant/concise as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with the data after transposing it, **pandas DataFrame** might be a good option for you in terms of "standard" library.

Something like (I haven't tested this, but this is the gist):

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(h1)
data_t = data.transpose()
```

`pandas` is a pretty powerful, performant, standard way of dealing with tables of data. You may also find methods there for how to create `h1` in the first place, as well as methods for analyzing the transposed result, etc.

Comment: "numpy DataFrame" ?